# How to filter and delete documents which have the same value in 2 fields. [Mongo 3.2]

Tags: mongodb

I have a documents which have following important fields:

```
{
  "ShownId": 4
  "PrerequisiteIds": [3,2,1]
}
```

What I would like to know is how to create a Mongo query which will allow me to filter out documents which have **ShownId** and **PrerequisiteIds** with the same value.

And afterwards, create a query which will allow me to delete these documents.

The filter query which I have right now looks like this:
`{ "ShownId": { $eq : "PrerequisiteIds"}}`

I am new to Mongo, but I know that it should be done by using *aggregate* function. I just dont know how to create the query.

Comment: It doesn't have to be done using the `aggregate()` method. Could you share what you already have tried?

Comment: @noam Well first I at least tried filtering it in Mongo Compass with something like:
`{"PrerequisiteIds": { $eq : "ShownId" }}`. But compass would not even allow me to submit this query.

Comment: I mean you should improve my question. Maybe your first question should be, how to fix your query to filter the documents.

Comment: @noam Did the edit you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `$expr` and `$in`:

As per payload:

```
{
    "ShownId": 4
    "PrerequisiteIds": [3,2,1]
}
```

Fetch Documents Query:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    $expr: {
        $in: ["$ShownId", "$PrerequisiteIds"]
    }
})
```

Remove Documents Query:

```
db.collection.remove({ 
    $expr: {
        $in: ["$ShownId", "$PrerequisiteIds"]
    }
})
```

Working playground for fetch documents: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cH1lbZDx8za

---

Might be this aggregation will work in v3.2:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      ShownId: 1,
      PrerequisiteIds: 1,
      hasValue: {
        $in: [
          "$ShownId",
          "$PrerequisiteIds"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      hasValue: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      hasValue: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working playground for fetch documents: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gdiGzTZ0mWh

Comment: @KnucklePunch have you resolved your problem with this answer?

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize the mongo version is 3.2, so this solution doesnt work for me. It return, that it doesnt know `$expr` command

Comment: Yes might be there is some issue in version 3.2, you can try aggregation that i have just edited in my answer.

Comment: Your answer doesnt solve the issue, its returning some errors. Will try different things. If I find an answer, will post it here. But thanks for start, will upvote the answer.

Comment: You can add mongo version 3.2 and its not working, so that will be clear for other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
db.collectionName.find({ $where : "this.ShownId == this.PrerequisiteIds" } );
```

But in case the collection will have lot of records then I wouldn't recommend doing this. Since in **where** clause **indexes** doesn't work.

Comment: No, it didnt. After 5 min returned empty array.

Comment: Oh strange. Worked fine for me. Approx. how many documents are there in your collection?